# Tap location on SCNNode in arkit ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, scnnode

I placed node1 to sceneview.I also added node2 as childnode to node1 when tapped on node1.But I am not able to place node2 correctly at tap location on node1.How can I place it exactly at tap location of scn node in arkit.

## Updated

**Final Code**

```
let sceneView = sender.view as! ARSCNView
let tapLocation = sender.location(in: sceneView)
let hitTest = sceneView.hitTest(tapLocation, options: [:])
guard let node = hitTest.first?.node.parent
if let hitTest = hitTest.first
{
    guard let scene = SCNScene(named: "furnitures.scnassets/(furnitureName).scn") else{return}
    let childnode = (scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: furnitureName + " " + "parentnode", recursively: false))!
     node.addChildNode(childnode)
     childnode.position = hitTest.localCoordinates
     childnode.scale = SCNVector3(0.5,0.5,0.5)
 }
```

Comment: where is your code ? you tried?

Comment: I posted plz check and help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `SCNHitTestResult` `localCoordinates` or `worldCoordinates` this depend of which one is better for your problem, then you can add a node on that position

**this is a example code**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    let touch = touches.first
    if let point = touch?.location(in: scnView) {
        let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(point, options: nil)
        if let result: SCNHitTestResult = hitResults.first {
            let position  = result.localCoordinates
            let position2  = result.worldCoordinates
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Melian..I did the same but the node2 is not placed at tap location.Is it related to node1 position or pivot?

Comment: Did you try both positions? @AnushaCheedella, can you provide your current code?

Comment: @AnushaCheedella if you are adding the new node into the touched one you need localCoordinates if you re adding Node2 into scene then you need WorldCoordinates

Answer (score 2):

This is my code.I didnot know how to mention in comment so I posted like this

```
let sceneView = sender.view as! ARSCNView
let tapLocation = sender.location(in: sceneView)
let hitTest = sceneView.hitTest(tapLocation, options: [:])
guard let node = hitTest.first?.node
if let hitTest = hitTest.first
{
    guard let scene = SCNScene(named: "furnitures.scnassets/(furnitureName).scn") else{return}
    let childnode = (scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: furnitureName + " " + "parentnode", recursively: false))!
     node.addChildNode(childnode)
     childnode.position = hitTest.localCoordinates
     childnode.scale = SCNVector3(0.5,0.5,0.5)
 }
```

Comment: I had added your answer as update in your question, now you can remove the answer if your want to

Comment: Did my answer help to fix your problem?

Comment: I am sorry bcz I am asking too many questions.I am beginner so I have many questions.Your answer helped me...In my first case I want to add a vase on chair..In this case everything is perfect.But when I add it on a table the vase is soo negligeble that I cannot see it..May I know where is the issue//

Comment: What you mean with "is soo negligeble"?

Comment: negligible means the size is so small when compared to when it is placed on chair

Comment: Check the childNode Scale maybe is related to parent node scale

Answer (score 0):

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQd35.jpg)

You can see the difference in the size of node2 when placed on chair and table.I circled on table so that it is visible...

Comment: Check the scale of the parent node , and the size of the parent node related to the vase object size